# 9 pin npn transmission relay issue

Tags: schematic

I've visited this site before never posted until now.
I just recently graduated with a bachelors in electrical engineering, and I'm trying to teach myself car electronics. I ran into this 9 pin relay that is supposed to be for a transmission. however I'm running into an issue when attempting to powering the transistors T2, and T3 in order to activate inductor L1 to close the switch attached to it.

Since this is a vehicle transmission I assume the power inputs are 12V DC.
I tried pin5 at 12V and pin7 at GND, then I tried tapping on and off pin9 with the same power source I plugged to pin5 and I cannot get current to flow from pin 5 to ground to get L1 to activate. maybe there is something simple Im missing. It's the first time I see this type of circuit on my and Im trying to activate it on my own. I assume pin3 triggers the inductors L1 or L2. Ive tried powering pins5, 6, and 9 at the same time, ive tried other configurations and nothing.

I tested the relays by tapping directly accross the inductors and they work. I just cant trigger them with the numbered pins out of the relay.

if anyone could guide me, or show me how to power it up and trigger the relays, I would greatly appreciate it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vQI3.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you ask a specific question?

Comment: There's a time delay circuit involving C1. Did you wait long enough? Since you have the device open, measure the voltages on the transistors to understand the circuit. If you can measure or read the resistances, you could simulate it.

Comment: @VoltageSpike Im trying to trigger or activate  the relays L1 and L2  with just the numbered pins coming out of the module housing. In other words Im trying to turn on the relays with pins 1-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transistor T3 must be turned on (forward biased) in order to conduct current from collector to emitter and energise the coil L1. This means that pin 9, which provides the forward bias current for T3 through R1 and R4, must be "high" (probably at 12V, since this is a 12V relay). Pins 1 and 3 form a diode-logic NAND gate. Any one of these pins being low will pull down the base of T3 (by diverting the bias current through R1 to ground) and turn it off, so both pins 1 and 3 must be "high".

Comment: Hi @AndyW, you were almost right. this helped me trigger L1, but instead of pins 1 and 3 being 'high' nothing happened. the inductor triggered when I put them low. However this saved me like a day of research, since I was putting only one pin high either 1 OR 3. You dont have to answer this but, how did you know pins 1 and 3 were a NAND?   

either way, thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm puzzled by needing to put both pins 1 and 3 low. That's not the way the circuit as shown should work. I'm now wondering whether the circuit diagram is accurate.I'm old enough to have designed logic circuits with DTL (Diode-Transistor Logic), in which NAND gate inputs always had paralleled diode "pull downs", one for each input of the NAND gate. (Actually, even some more modern TTL logic gates were built this way)